# R - Write a raster object with the pixels transparency attribute

Tags: raster, r, export, tiles, transparency-opacity

In R, I have a raster object for which I would like to set a certain level of transparency. When I visualize it, everything is fine

```
library(raster)

test <- raster(x = matrix(1:16, 4))

plot(test,
     alpha = 0.25)
```

but now I would like to write my raster in .tif format through the `writeRaster()` function. Is it possible to store the level of transparency at the pixel level?

I need this step because, starting from the .tif object, I would like to produce **tiles** of such raster that will be displayed as basemaps Leaflet inside an online application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking a tiff (GeoTIFF) file is a means to store data. You are trying to store visualization metadata as a part of that file. While this might be possible, I would think twice before doing so: Usually visualization applications such as leaflet tiles allow you to set the transparency (opacity) value in the application itself (one example: [Leaflet - Opacity method for L.tileLayer.wms?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217429/leaflet-opacity-method-for-l-tilelayer-wms)).

If you really want to create a transparency (alpha) band for the GeoTIFF file, you can do so with gdal after writing out the raster to GeoTIFF with R as explained in this thread: [Adding transparency to Geotiff files](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228730/adding-transparency-to-geotiff-files).